# Nodejs MongoDB query doesn't work as expected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Can someone explain why my simple update/set query doesn't work? I do the query via nodejs using mongoose with promises. Here's my schema:
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

```
var usersSchema = mongoose.Schema ({
    username:String,
    password:String,
    home_planet:Number,
    last_planet:Number,
    experience:Number,
    money:Number
}, {collection: 'account', versionKey: false});

module.exports = usersSchema;
```

And here's my function for update/set value in database

```
    const usersSchema = require('./userSchema');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var userModel = mongoose.model('userModel', usersSchema);

userModel.setUserGold = setUserGold;

        function setUserGold(username, newGold) {
            return userModel.updateOne({username:username}, {
                $set: {experience:newGold}
            });
        }
```

And the call to the function

```
userModel.setUserGold('test', 500);
```

Where test is the username and 500 is the value of gold to add into the database for that username, but nothing gets set/updated?

Comment: Is your function async?

Comment: For debugging purpose try giving upsert:true. This will Create a new document if no documents match the filter.

Comment: @Mr.Gandhi I believe mongoose queries are async by default, aren't they? I have tried adding upsert: true, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue by adding .then() to the calling function, ex:

```
userModel.setUserGold('test', 500)
.then((res) => {
   if (!res) return;
   console.log('player updated');
});
```

I am not sure why I didn't worked without .then() I have tried this same function before without adding .then() and it was working just fine, but in one moment it stopped working until i added .then() If somebody can explain that it will mean a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem in your first Version is, that you are not providing a Callback or handling the returning Promise if no Callback is provided by the updateOne Function. See here from @types/mongoose the definition:

`updateOne(conditions: any, doc: any,
 callback?: (err: any, raw: any) => void): Query<any> & QueryHelpers;`

To resolve your Problem, provide a callback for the updateOne Function or handle the Promise like you did in your second version.